# selecionar nome unico na tabela mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, tenho uma duvida constante quando selecionar algo no mysql, tenho um tabela mysql que contem um coluna chamada Nome nela contem os seguintes valores

|nome
|Aline
|Alice
|Aline
|Valdemord
|Aline

e outra coluna chamada ID
nela contendo

1|1|2|2|3|3|

bom nelas a duvida é a seguinte, como eu faria para selecionar por exemplo, buscar nelas as nomes unicos e imprimir cada nome apenas uma vez, no entando se tem 2 Aline, mostre apenas uma Aline, e no caso do valores dessa segunda tabela de ids, mostre algo do time todos do id 1 sejam do TIME 1 todos de ID sejam do time VERMELHO.

Comment: já tentou usar `distinct`? `SELECT DISTINCT nome FROM Tabela`

Answer (score 1):

Você tem 2 opções, pode usar o Group by e o Distinct 
Exemplo com o group by:

```
select id, nome from  tabela
    where ....
    group by nome
```

Exemplo com o distinct:

```
select DISTINCT nome, id from  tabela
    where ....
```